# Save the responses and write them later in Csv in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, it is possible to send Requests without waiting for responses. For this, it is enough to write the Response in 1 milliseconds in the Advanced part of the HTTP Request section:
Question: When I want to increase the number of requests, how can I do it so that I don't wait for the responses, but I can save the responses somewhere and use them to write to Csv later?

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) it's not possible to implement using normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, if you decrease response timeout JMeter will terminate the underlying [TCP connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) when the timeout occurs and response will never come.

The only way I can think of is using [JSR223 Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) for sending the requests using [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-http-request), you can make them run in background using [Future tasks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-future) however in that case you will need to not only handle the responses yourself but also think about of collecting metrics like connect time, latency, response time and so on, basically you will need to re-create the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) if you want to use JMeter [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) or [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) for results analysis.